# TypeScript: Is there a cleaner way to null check a hierarchical object structure?

Tags: typescript, nullpointerexception

I'm currently null checking an object structure like so:

```
if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.errorMessage)
{
  // Do stuff
}
```

All I really want to do is null check the deepest variable `error.response.data.errorMessage`, but because I want to avoid null pointer exceptions in the check I have to first check `error.response`, and then `error.response.data`.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? I imagine as you want to query deeper and deeper into the hierarchy it can get quite messy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**optional chaining**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
if (error.response?.data?.errorMessage) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Magic, just what I was looking for. Thanks!